# Can I host my front end in one hosting service and the backend somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting, cloud-hosting

I have a website hosted in justhost.com. So far it is only HTML/CSS/JS done all from scratch. Recently I have been learning about Server Side Java Script (SSJS) using nodejs and I would like to add some JS backend processing to my site. The problem is that justhost.com does not seem to support nodejs applications, so now I am kind of stuck.

Is there a way to keep all the front end of my site (HTML, CSS and front end JS) hosted in justhost.com and then build the backend in nodejs SSJS and keep that part hosted in another service or server and somehow make it all work together?

Right not it is not a commercial application, so I can play around and break things, so I am open to any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The complete answer is "probably, but it's complicated" due to restrictions built into the web itself like cross-origin isolation as well as hosting provider restrictions. However, since you are asking this, my suggestion is just host your entire application (server side code, HTML, CSS, browser JS, images, etc) on a node.js hosting service since they all support that and it's trivial to do. No reason to complicate your architecture to stick with a static web host. It takes a handful of lines of "code" in your node app to have a fully functional static web site served along with any custom server-side logic your application may also need. (consider the `static` middleware bundled with the `express.js` application server, for example).

Comment: Fair enough. Which "node.js" hosting services do you recommend?

Comment: I don't use them, so hard to say. nodejitsu or heroku seem like reasonable choices based on my very shallow exposure to them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter Lyons answer but in case you really want to do this, the way I would do this is to treat your nodejs server as a rest api (or even SOAP api) and your front end server would treat your nodejs server as a database where it would require information from it like `backendserver.com/users` which would return your front end the users.. Or even better is your front end would have the UI code with the link to backendserver and then they would be loaded from the browser.. That's typically how your set up is handled